# Connect Points in a grid in Opencv Python. Polyline gives zig-zag lines

Tags: python, opencv, drawing

I have points in OpenCV as

```
parkPoints=
array([[208, 335],
   [258, 328],
   [236, 446],
   [186, 453],
   [308, 321],
   [286, 439],
   [358, 314],
   [336, 432],
   [408, 307],
   [386, 425],
   [458, 300],
   [436, 418],
   [508, 293],
   [486, 411],
   [558, 286],
   [536, 404]])
```

I am trying to connect the lines to form the grid. I used openCV Polyline method as

```
pts = parkPoints.reshape((-1,1,2))
cv2.polylines(im_dst,[pts],True,(0,255,255))    
cv2.imshow("Image", im_dst)
```

I get perfect connection with first 4-Elements of array. But when I expand it, it connects wrong points and it looks zig-zag.

Not sure I need to format/order the elements in specific way or missing something

Comment: First try plotting all the points by drawing them using `cv2.circle`. After that you will come to know the alignment of the points. Once you know that, order the points sequentially and then draw polylines. Drawing polylines for an irregular set of points WILL give zig-zag lines

Comment: Were you able to figure out a way around?